# Python global variable in if - elif

Tags: python, if-statement

Sorry if it’s dumb question, I am not a programmer. Just wanted to understand how global variables are handled in if elif statement.  The global variable x (Boolean) may be updated elsewhere at high frequency So I need the x to be the same in both If and elif conditional statements. Does the underlying code use the same value of x in both statements or does it read the global variable each time, thus meaning it may be different in the two conditional statements?

Hope that makes sense?

E.g.

```
global x

if x and not status:
    # Do some stuff

elif not x and status:
    # do some other stuff
```

This is just a question trying to understand how global variables are handled

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: I believe the answer would be compiler-dependent. Some optiomizations could occur on reading the value just once, then using the same register on both tests without re-reading it. Interesting question however.

Comment: Another thing to clear up, you have a `global` statement that doesn't do anything, it is *in the global scope*. But also, even if we imagine we are in a local scope, you don't need `global x` to *merely reference a global variable in a nonglobal scope*. You only need that `global` statement to *assign* to a global variable in a non-global scope. i.e. assignments are by default *local*

Comment: @PoneyUHC no, absolutly not. That would violate Python's semantics.

Comment: It would read `x` each time it needs it; if you have another thread updating `x`, you have a *race condition*. You would want to use a lock to ensure that no other thread can update `x` while you are using it.

Comment: There's nothing special about `if/elif`. They're no different from any other sequential statements that refer to the same variable.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't done much parallel programming, but if you're only reading the value and not changing it in this section of code, the solution could be as simple as `y = x; if y ...`. Otherwise I think you would have to put a lock on any section of code that modifies `x`.

Comment: *"global variable x (Boolean) may be updated elsewhere at high frequency"* This doesn't detract from your question, however this design seems to be a textbook example supporting the, sometimes pretty dogmatic, *global variables are evil* memes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: @JLPeyret True, although the problem would be the same if they were using some other shared data structure to communicate among the threads.

Comment: @Barmar Quite likely.  Still, if there is one situation where a global seems inadvisable and more isolation and immutability would be nice this Q seems to personify it.

Comment: @JLPeyret I think the point of this code is that he wants to have this shared state between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, your code will load the value `x` two different times for you in the `if` and `elif` conditions, respectively. The `global` nature of that variable doesn't really factor in to that (it would be the same with local variables in a function).

If you want to only read `x` once, you can rewrite your compound conditions to instead use an `if` and `else` for the test of `x`, with inner `if` statements that handle testing `status`:

```
if x:
    if not status:
        # do stuff
else:                  # this is the big change, no second test of x here!
    if status:
        # do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out as a possible approach, with minimal impact on the overall decision structure, if `x` is a simple variable.  `copy.deepcopy` *may* work on more complex variables.

This is similar to using `y = x` when x is immutable, as mentioned in a comment.

However, as remarked in my comment, a design relying on a [fast-mutating global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/1394353) to drive processing and decisions seems to be asking for trouble.

```
import copy

global x

#take a copy and then use for this pass 
x2 = copy.copy(x)


if x2 and not status:
    # Do some stuff

elif not x2 and status:
    # do some other stuff
```